# Comiling linux perf tools and its dependent kernel modules from source/scratch

Tags: performance, ubuntu, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, flamegraph

I am using linux perf tool for profiling shared library. Though it worked well on Ubuntu but now I want to run it on embedded linux and I cannot use apt-get to install linux perf tools on embedded linux. That's why I should have to compile everything from scratch.

Can anyone please guide how to compile linux perf tools and dependent kernel module from scratch/source.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Arslan Ali

Comment: "Can anyone please guide how to compile linux perf tools and dependent kernel module from scratch/source." - On Stack Overflow we don't write **guides** and other tutorials.  **Try** to compile the tools, and if you have faced a concrete problem, then search for that problem, and if nothing helps, then ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks alot for your response and I will look for possible solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Source code of perf is found in linux-kernel/tools/perf. So use the same kernel which use are using for your board.

For building the perf tools, go to the perf directory as told above. Then run the below command

## These commands will change based on your cross toolchain

```
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

After building is over copy the perf binary to your board /bin directory and
add the execution permission to it. Then you can use this feature.

Comment: Thanks so what I tried few days ago is to clone below repository                                  
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git                      and then   cd linux/tools/perf && make. And finally cp perf/usr/bin.                                 But the issue the above link will clone the whole kernel and its files size are huge.

Comment: You just mentioned that you are using embedded linux. This means you will have linux kernel source code for your board.

Comment: Yes this was ultimate requitment of the project but what I was trying first is to test how I can compile perf tools from source on my notebook with ubuntu.

Comment: For your testing you can download the tar file which will be shorter. For example ,  https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.9.97.tar.xz.


Similarly the list of all the kernel is as below :
https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/

Comment: sound great. Thanks alot. Will be looking into those very shortly.

Comment: I tried with the above tar file and it work perfectly fine. The only thing which I want to ask is before doing make in linux/tools/perf it requires two additional dependencies i.e. flex and bison and I want to avoid installing them using apt-get